# golang json unstructured data

Tags: arrays, json, go

I have a json (unstructured) and wants to retrieve each and every key from the json data
Then loop through the keys and value. If the value is of type json (nested) or array then keep continuing.

I have found an example of structured json parsing but cannot get this.
Checked this code but could not get the complete one

```
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &customers)
```

Sample json:

```json
{
    "components": [
        {
            "key": "d1",
            "components": [
                {
                    "key": "custname",
                    "value": "Abraham",
                    "input": true,
                    "tableView": true
                },
                {
                    "key": "type",
                    "type": "radio",
                    "label": "Fisrt",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "label": "Sole",
                            "value": "sole",
                            "shortcut": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Bata",
                            "value": "Bata",
                            "shortcut": ""
                        }
                    ],
                    "validate": {
                        "required": true
                    },
                    "tableView": false
                },
                {
                    "key": "registeredField",
                    "value": "reg 111",
                    "input": true,
                },
                {
                    "key": "dirc",
                    "value": "abraham",
                },
                {
                    "key": "gst",
                    "value": "textfield",                   
                    "useLocaleSettings": false
                },
                {
                    "key": "pan",
                    "value": "AAAAA0000",                    
                    "useLocaleSettings": false
                }
            ],
            "collapsible": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
Key: custname Value: Abraham
Key: type Value: {
    "label": "Sole",
    "value": "sole",
    "shortcut": ""
}, {
    "label": "Bata",
    "value": "Bata",
    "shortcut": ""
}
Key: registeredField Value: reg 111
```

Comment: Edit the question to show the type of variable `customers`, the code that you tried and the problem you encountered.

Comment: ... and please include an example of the "unstructured json" as well.

Comment: ... and the desired result from that "unstructured json".

Comment: Every aspect of JSON unmarshaling in Go has been answered on SO already.

Comment: The expected output is not JSON or a Go value. It's unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: @RohanDsouza what format is the expected output? Should that be a Go map? a slice of structs? or something else? In `Key: custname Value: Abraham` is `Key` a field name? or the key in a map? What do you want it to be?

Comment: @RohanDsouza here's one attempt to provide the expected output: https://play.golang.org/p/XgYr_Yuuc_a but without more info it's hard to know whether that's exactly what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

So you have an object with a key `components`, that is a slice of components. Each of these components can have a number of keys. First thing to do is to take stock of all possible fields a component can have and define a type with said fields:

```
type Validation struct {
    Required bool `json:"required"`
}

type Value struct {
    Label    string `json:"label"`
    Value    string `json:"value"`
    Shortcut string `json:"shortcut"`
}

type Data struct {
    Components        []Data      `json:"components,omitempty"`
    Collapsable       bool        `json:"collapsable"`
    Input             bool        `json:"input"`
    Key               string      `json:"key"`
    TableView         bool        `json:"tableView"`
    Type              string      `json:"type"`
    Value             string      `json:"value"`
    UseLocaleSettings bool        `json:"useLocaleSettings"`
    Values            []Value     `json:"values,omitempty"`
    Validate          *Validation `json:"validate,omitempty"`
}
```

Now you simply take the input and unmarshal it into the `Data` type:

```
data := Data{}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &data); err != nil {
    // handle error
    fmt.Printf("Oops, something went wrong: %+v", err)
    return
}
```

At this point, we have all the data in a struct, so we can start printing it all out. First thing we notice is how `Data` basically contains a slice of `Data` types. A recursive function to print it all out would make sense:

```
func PrintComponents(data []Data) {
    for _, c := range data {
        if len(c.Components) > 0 {
            PrintComponents(c.Components) // recursive
            continue                      // skip value of this component, remove this line if needed
        }
        val := c.Value // assign string value
        if len(c.Values) > 0 {
            // this component has a slice of values, not a single value
            vals, err := json.MarshalIndent(c.Values, "", "    ") // marshal with indent of 4 spaces, no prefix
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Oops, looks like we couldn't format something: %+v\n", err)
                return // handle this
            }
            val = string(vals) // marshalled values as string
        }
        fmt.Printf("Key: %s Value: %s\n", c.Key, val) // print output
    }
}
```

You could alter this function a bit to pass in an indent parameter for each level of recursion, so you can print out the components in indented blocks:

```
func PrintComponents(data []Data, indent string) {
    for _, c := range data {
        if len(c.Components) > 0 {
            // print the key for this block of components
            fmt.Printf("Component block: %s\n", c.Key)
            PrintComponents(data, indent + "    ") // current indent + 4 spaces
            continue // we're done with this component
        }
        val := c.Value
        if len(c.Values) > 0 {
            vals, _ := json.MarshalIndent(c.Values, indent, "    ") // pass in indent level here, and DON'T ignore the error, that's just for brevity
            val = string(vals)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%sKey: %s Value: %s\n", indent, c.Key, val) // pass in indent
    }
}
```

Putting it all together, we get [this](https://play.golang.org/p/Kq95Gfwjzak):

```
func main() {
    data := Data{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(input, &data); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Printing with simple recursive function")
    // print all components, these could be nested, so let's use a recursive function
    PrintComponents(data.Components)
    fmt.Println("\n\nPrinting with indented recursion:")
    PrintComponentsIndent(data.Components, "") // start with indent of 0
}

func PrintComponents(data []Data) {
    for _, c := range data {
        if len(c.Components) > 0 {
            PrintComponents(c.Components) // recursive
            continue                      // skip value of this component, remove this line if needed
        }
        val := c.Value // assign string value
        if len(c.Values) > 0 {
            // this component has a slice of values, not a single value
            vals, err := json.MarshalIndent(c.Values, "", "    ") // marshal with indent of 4 spaces, no prefix
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("Oops, looks like we couldn't format something: %+v\n", err)
                return // handle this
            }
            val = string(vals) // marshalled values as string
        }
        fmt.Printf("Key: %s Value: %s\n", c.Key, val) // print output
    }

}

func PrintComponentsIndent(data []Data, indent string) {
    for _, c := range data {
        if len(c.Components) > 0 {
            fmt.Printf("%sComponent block: %s\n", indent, c.Key)
            PrintComponentsIndent(c.Components, indent + "    ")
            continue
        }
        val := c.Value
        if len(c.Values) > 0 {
            // this component has a slice of values, not a single value
            vals, _ := json.MarshalIndent(c.Values, indent, "    ")
            val = string(vals) // marshalled values as string
        }
        fmt.Printf("%sKey: %s Value: %s\n", indent, c.Key, val) // print output
    }

}
```

Which outputs:

```
Printing with simple recursive function
Key: custname Value: Abraham
Key: type Value: [
    {
        "label": "Sole",
        "value": "sole",
        "shortcut": ""
    },
    {
        "label": "Bata",
        "value": "Bata",
        "shortcut": ""
    }
]
Key: registeredField Value: reg 111
Key: dirc Value: abraham
Key: gst Value: textfield
Key: pan Value: AAAAA0000


Printing with indented recursion:
Component block: d1
    Key: custname Value: Abraham
    Key: type Value: [
        {
            "label": "Sole",
            "value": "sole",
            "shortcut": ""
        },
        {
            "label": "Bata",
            "value": "Bata",
            "shortcut": ""
        }
    ]
    Key: registeredField Value: reg 111
    Key: dirc Value: abraham
    Key: gst Value: textfield
    Key: pan Value: AAAAA0000
```

Your desired output doesn't include the square brackets for the values slice. Well, that's a really easy thing to get rid of. The square brackets are always the first and last characters of the string, and `json.Marshal` returns a byte slice (`[]byte`). Chopping off the first and last characters is as easy as:

```
val = string(vals[1:len(vals)-2])
```

Taking a sub-slice of the byte slice returned by `json.Marshal`, starting at offset 1 (cutting of offset 0, which is `[`), and keeping everything until the next to last character (offset `len(vals)-2`). For the indented example, that will leave you with a blank line, containing an unknown number of spaces (indentation). You can trim the right-hand side of the string using the `strings` package:

```
// remove square brackets, trim trailing new-line and spaces
val = strings.TrimRight(string(vals[1:len(vals)-2]), "\n ")
```